# Adobe Http Dynamic Streaming(HDS) vs HTTP Adaptive Streaming MPEG-DASH(HAS)

Tags: video-streaming, adobe, http-live-streaming, adaptive-bitrate

What is the difference between Adobe Http dynamic streaming and HTTP MPEG-DASH adaptive streaming

As per my understanding both are http based..

What is so unique about HAS MPEG-DASH that makes it better than Adobe HDS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are competitors. Besides differences in the file container format, The largest difference is Adobe. DASH does not have a for profit company behind it. It is a standard developed by standards bodies. This tends to lead to better compatibility, better open source tools, and cheeper deployment.

Comment: if you explain "difference in file container format" what you mean by that..Thanks

Comment: both DASH and HDS use a superset of ISO/IEC 14496-12. But they each invented their own superset. So the format is similar, but ultimately different.